# Extends Guzzle 6 default response

Tags: php, http, guzzle, guzzle6

How can I extends the default guzzle response object?

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://foo.com/api/']);
$response = $client->request('GET', 'test'); // I want my own class instance here
```

The current goal is to add a `json` function in response (but it could be something else). I'm a lost in guzzle 6 documentation.

Comment: Why was it downvoted?

Comment: I would just add on top of the accepted answer docs for the middlewares, which explains how this all work can be found here: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html so if you want deeper understanding read that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly advise against extending `GuzzleHttp\Http\Message\Response` via inheritance.  The recommended method would be to use composition to implement `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface` and then proxy all calls to the ResponseInterface methods to the enclosed object.  This would maximize its usability.

```
class JsonResponse implements Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface {
    public function __construct(Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response) {
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    public function getHeaders() {
        return $this->response->getHeaders();
    }

    public function getBodyAsJson() {
        return json_decode($this->response->getBody()->__toString());
    }
    // I will leave the remaining methods of the Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface for you to look up.
}
```

Information on the ResponseInterface can be found [here](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/) and [here](https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/ResponseInterface.php)

You don't attach it to the client so much as you attach middleware to the stack handler.

```
$stack->push(GuzzleHttp\Middleware::mapResponse(function Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response) {
    return new JsonResponse($response);  
});
```

More information on Guzzle Middleware can be found [here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html).

Comment: Ok, thanks. "I would strongly advise against extending `GuzzleHttp\Http\Message\Response`" -> why? it seems easier. If `GuzzleHttp\Http\Message\Response` implements `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface` there is no risk of breaking something (thanks to the interface) and I only want to use it with guzzle (so no needs to maximize its usability). Anyway, even if I implements the interface, how can I attach it to the client?